# Creating pattern restriction for xml attribute for xsd verification

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, xsd-validation

I am creating XSD for an XML which has an element as below with an attribute whose value I want to restrict to few values as defined below values of X.

```
<Element Attribute = "X">
```

where X can either be "-1" or L1 to L50 or U1 to U10

I am working on creating restriction on Attribute value for above Attribute.
I thought of using pattern matching here and came up with a pattern as below but it is not working. Can somebody suggest why it is not working and what pattern i should use to serve my requirement.

```
<xs:attribute name="Attribute">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="(\-1) | ([L][1-30]) | ([U][1-11])"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
```

Comment: Your regex is wrong.  Use a regex tester to build the correct syntax.